Cleaning carbon deposits from brass
I’m looking for a reasonable way to remove carbon deposits from brass. Specifically smokeless powder residue from cartridge brass. At present I use Acetone warmed to about 50C in a water bath and then ultrasound, but I’m wondering if there is a better solvent to loosen/dissolve the soot without damaging the brass or needing lots of protective equipment.

I have no soot around (hence a comment instead of an answer) but already volatile acetone close to 50C is almost boiling, i.e. it goes off into the air which isn't good for your health. And it is flammable, too. I would try a mix of water and white vinegar (often a surprisingly good adjustable solvent mix in the lab) but put on googles to keep your eyes safe, and gloves to protect the skin of your hands. The idea of an ultrasound cleaner is a good one to clean small grooves instead/complementary to using a brush. If too concentrated in acid/exposed for too long, brass might corrode a bit.

Thank you.
Yes I’m aware that is close to BP. It’s heated indirectly via water in the ultrasonic cleaner. No naked flames or ignition sources and a well ventilated area. Thank you however as safety is essential.
With respect to vinegar (acetic acid) unfortunately the acid attacks the brass, and the nature of use means the brass strength can’t be compromised; hence the use of organic solvents.
I genuinely appreciate your comments though. Thank you.

Soot or carbon are at room conditions chemically inert and insoluble. The only available ways is the old good mechanics of abrasion, using solvent to reach crevices and dissolve fatty  components and release some carbon, or using detergents to disperse less firmly bound carbon particles.

Interesting idea could be using such a brass object as cathode for water electrolysis. Evolving hydrogen bubbles could make some mechanical cleaning of hard to reach pits/scratches.

Electrolysis sounds interesting. I confess I hadn’t thought of that.  I suspect it would need to be distilled water to prevent deposition or other chemical reactions happening with the brass.

Today I learned there is dry tumbler cleaning of reusable cartridges (example). According to tutorials around (like this advertisement), steal pins (example), or walnut shells then remove residues on either side.

I’m aware of them but they’re not that effective, and lose their own problems in terms of removing the tumbling media.
